# Jenkins Pipeline, PowerShell script hangs

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run a Powershell file from the Jenkins Pipeline, using the powershell command. Should be easy, right?

```
node()
{
    stage ('Hello World') {
        powershell returnStatus: true, script: 'C:\\HelloWorld.ps1'
    }   
}
```

C:\HelloWorld.ps1 is a one-liner:

```
Write-Host "Hello World"
```

But running the job causes the process to hang. Here is the console output:

```
Started by user Administrator
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in C:\Jenkins\workspace\HelloWorld
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Hello World)
[Pipeline] powershell
[HelloWorld] Running PowerShell script
```

And then it just hangs until I cancel the job.

What to do?

Comment: Not 100% sure but it's probably because you're using `Write-Host`, which explicitly writes to the console (and as your script probably runs non-interactively this causes it to hang). Change it to `Write-Output` or just the string on it's own `"Hello World"`.

Comment: @MarkWragg Thanks, but the same result, I'm afraid. I now see that I can even delete HelloWorld.ps1 file and the job still hangs. Why is there no error message???

Comment: Probably, it's because I have not upgraded to PowerShell version 3. Jenkins Pipeline requires at least version 3.

Comment: No, it must be something else. I'm actually on version 4!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it with downgrading DurableTask plugin from 1.17 to 1.15. It seems to be part of [JENKINS-46496](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46496) bug. The older plugin version is there [1.15](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/durable-task/).

You can update the plugin to a needed version in Manage Plugins->Advanced Tab->Upload Plugin button.

Comment: I confirm: downgrade Durable Task Plugin from 1.17 to 1.15 has solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: Downgrading caused other plugins to stop working, since they required 1.17. Something to keep in mind for others.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the problem was that the job had spaces in its name.

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be fixed in the next release: https://github.com/jenkinsci/durable-task-plugin/pull/51

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in about 70 % of my cases. I have a pipeline script that kicks off about 20 parallel jobs spread out over different agents. Each of these tries to run a Powershell script initially. About 30 % of the jobs succeed to run the script, the rest hangs just like it does for Ola.

The build agents are configured exactly the way (clones in a VM cluster). Powershell v4 is used. Upon several tries one single build agent sometimes succeeds in running Powershell, sometimes don't.

I've been running this pipeline for 5-6 weeks and it's just the last week this behavior has been seen. Fortunately the script isn't in production yet :-)

I haven't had the time to do a full investigation. Could it be that some of the pipeline plugins have been updated and introduced this bug?

Comment: See Володимир Ковбасюк answer above. It solved my problem to revert that plugin.